# SQL Rows to Separate Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realise this maybe similar to other questions, but I am stuck!

I am having trouble organising some data into an appropriate format to export to another tool. Basically I have an ID column and then 2 response columns. I would like to separate the ID and then list the responses under each. See the example below for clarification.

I have played around with Pivot and UnPivot but can't get it quite right.

Here is how the data looks now.

```
ID  X1  X2  
1   2   Y   
1   5   Y   
1   3   N   
1   7   N   
1   6   Y   
2   5   N   
2   4   Y   
2   8   Y   
2   3   N   
3   5   Y   
3   1   N   
3   9   N
```

Here is how I would like the data to look

```
ID1_X1    ID1_X2    ID2_X1    ID2_X2    ID3_X1    ID3_X2  
  2         Y         5         N         5         Y     
  5         Y         4         Y         1         N     
  3         N         8         Y         9         N     
  7         N         3         N         null      null  
  6         Y         null      null      null      null
```

Here is the code to create/populate the table.

```
create table #test (ID int, X1 int, X2 varchar(1))

insert into #test values
('1','2','Y'),('1','5','Y'),('1','3','N'),('1','7','N'),
('1','6','Y'),('2','5','N'),('2','4','Y'),('2','8','Y'),
('2','3','N'),('3','5','Y'),('3','1','N'),('3','9','N')
```

Comment: Is there any other column to define the *order* of `X1` in each `ID`

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s have added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation and `row_number()` . . . assuming you know the ids in advance:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then x1 end) as x1_1,
       max(case when id = 1 then x2 end) as x2_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then x1 end) as x1_2,
       max(case when id = 2 then x2 end) as x2_2,
       max(case when id = 3 then x1 end) as x1_3,
       max(case when id = 3 then x2 end) as x2_3       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) a seqnum
      from #test t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

I should note that SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Your original data doesn't have an indication of the ordering, so this is not guaranteed to put the values in the same order as the original data (actually, there is *no* such order that that statement is a tautology).  If you have another column with the ordering, then you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a alternative approach to Gordan's good answer using `OUTER JOIN's`

Considering that there is a Identity column in your table to define the order of `X1` in each `ID` and fixed number of `ID's`

```
;WITH FST
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY IDENTITY_COL) RN,X1 AS ID1_X1,X2 AS ID1_X2
         FROM   #TEST A
         WHERE  ID = 1),
     SCD
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY IDENTITY_COL) RN,X1 AS ID2_X1,X2 AS ID2_X2
         FROM   #TEST A
         WHERE  ID = 2),
     TRD
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY IDENTITY_COL) RN,X1 AS ID3_X1,X2 AS ID3_X2
         FROM   #TEST A
         WHERE  ID = 3)
SELECT ID1_X1,ID1_X2,ID2_X1,ID2_X2,ID3_X1,ID3_X2
FROM   FST A
       FULL OUTER JOIN SCD B
                    ON A.RN = B.RN
       FULL OUTER JOIN TRD C
                    ON C.RN = COALESCE(B.RN, A.RN)
```

Comment: Have accepted Gordon's answer, however I can confirm this works well also if you have a unique identifier for each row. Thanks!